# com.google.android.maps missing?

Tags: android

new to Android.  Checked the FAQs on the SDK site but didn't find anything that was helpful.

I'm learning via a few books w/downloadable code.  One of the examples I'd like to get running won't even compile because the IDE can't find/import the **com.google.android.maps** library/package, which I found odd since I have everything possible installed that the SDK offers.  The book info on the publisher site was not helpful either.  Any ideas?

I'm using Eclipse (build 20090920-1017) with the ADT 0.9.5 plugin.  SDK is fully updated (all available packages installed, including android 1.1 api 2 rev. 1 through android 2.0.1 api6 rev 1, and google apis 3 rev 3 through 6 rev 1.)

Any advice is appreciated.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Choose "Google API" project Build Target. And be sure Google API is installed in you Android SDK.
And don't forget to add

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

into  tag in ApplicationManifest.xml

Comment: << Choose "Google API" project Build Target >>

That was it, thanks! :)

Comment: Also if you're emulating, make sure the emulated machine targets Google API.

Answer (score 14):

Switch to  "Google API" as project Build Target works for me.

Project->properties->android,
check GOOGLE API

Answer (score 1):

1. Install all google API's using sdk manager.
2. In your manifest,under application element add

   ```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   ```
3. You have to include jar file for maps also.. Right click on your project and go to build path and then add external archives. locate your sdk. `android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon_google_apis_google_inc_<your api version>\libs\maps`

Answer (score 0):

Remember always to add uses library in appication branch. Like this:

I had also the same problem but i had added uses library not in application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.MapsTest"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0.0">
     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MapsTest"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Parsed in 0.004 seconds, using GeSHi 1.0.8.4

Answer (score 0):

Me too got this Error even though I Inserted

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

I struggled to solve this problem for a long time...

Then **Cleaning** and **Rebuilding** Project solves the Issue

Answer (score 0):

To develop with google maps I recommend you to use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) instead eclipse emulator.

Comment: I am having same issue with Genymotion, not with eclipse's emulator.
:?